# Cannot read property 'context' of undefined with css-blocks and webpack

Tags: css, webpack, linkedin-api

Here is my webpack config: https://hastebin.com/esipapepiz.js

I am trying to use https://github.com/linkedin/css-blocks

I am using create-react-app and I have ejected. I am trying to run the dev server and I get the message from my title. The docs seem pretty hard to follow so I am not sure what I am doing wrong?

```
yarn run v1.3.2
$ node scripts/start.js
Failed to compile.

Cannot read property 'context' of undefined

error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Comment: Ehm, the code in the hastebin doesn't contain the text "context".

Comment: that's why i am confused. i think it's an issue within css-blocks but it does not give me a good stack trace.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same error. I ejected the `create-react-app` in TypeScript and I've added css-blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Still little confused with your question because you didn't mention what the webpack version you used. I assumed that you used webpack version v4.0.0. context is working fine with earlier version of webpack.

**webpack v4.0.0 changed** this.context => this.rootContext

Do like this.it's a sample code snap

```js
+    var name = slash(path.relative(root || this.rootContext || this.options.context, this.resourcePath));
```

Comment: i was using webpack 3.8.1. do you think css blocks is made for webpack 4?

Comment: Hi, I think the issue with css plugins.please try to change the plugin 
  module.exports =  {
  plugins: [
    /* ... */
    new CssBlocksPlugin({
      name: "css-blocks",
      outputCssFile: "my-output-file.css",
      analyzer: analyzerInstance,
      compilationOptions: cssBlocksCompilationOptions,
      optimization: opticssOptimizationOptions
    }),
    /* ... */
  ],
  /* ... */
};